# Will DynamicResource cause memory leak?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

Will dynamicresource cause meomry leak?. Expression Blend is using mostly DyanamicResource instead of StaticResource. I read from different docs saying that use StaticResource to avoid memory leak?. If it is true then why expression blend is heavily using DyanmicResource? If we want to implement the theme or onfly style change we have to dynamicResource?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it can cause memory leaks, check the following link:

[DynamicResource\StaticResource cause memory leaks](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b97a5f83-5394-430e-9a78-9d3a957e3537/)